# Нестандартный синтаксис &

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня есть два файлс .cpp и один заголовочный ".h". Я решил вывести результат GenCan1 в main,но выдается такая ошибка (
Ошибка  C3867   "TElection::GetCan1": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член)

```
 main.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <EClass.h>
    #include <stdafx.h>
    using namespace std;

     int main() {
         std::cout << TElection::GetCan1<<std::endl;
         system("pause");
    }



EClass.h
    class TElection
    {
    protected:
        float can1, can2, can3;
    public:
        TElection();
        TElection(TElection &el);
        TElection(float a, float b, float c);
        ~TElection();

        float GetCan1();
        void SetCan1(float i);

    };



Election.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <EClass.h>
#include <stdafx.h>

TElection::TElection() {
    can1 = 0;
}
TElection::TElection(TElection& el) {
    can1 = el.can1;
}

TElection::TElection(float a, float b, float c) {
    can1 = a;
}

TElection::~TElection() {
    can1 = -1;

}
float TElection::GetCan1() {
    return(can1);
}
void TElection::SetCan1(float i) {
    if ((i >= 10) && (i < 0))
        can1 = 10;
    else
        can1 = i;
    std::cout << "can1=" << can1;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте `()`, чтобы обозначить вызов функции. А ещё почитайте о том, как стоит приводить код в вопросах: [mcve].

Comment: если поставить () , то выдается ошибка (
нестатическая ссылка не член должна указываться относительно заданного объекта)

Comment: Ну так создайте объект заданного класса, значит, для которого функция вызывается :)

Comment: Ну я хочу вызвать результат класса float TElection::GetCan1(). Ведь в SetCan1 задается значение can1 и выводится с помощью класса GetCan1.

Comment: Функция `GetCan1()` не является статической `static`, а значит, чтобы её можно было вызвать, нужно предоставить экземпляр класса `TElection`, создать объект, т.е. Например, так: `TElection obj;` и дальше вызывать для объекта `obj` функцию: `obj.GetCan1()`. Обо всём этом говорится в любом учебнике по языку в базовой его части.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

Если вы действительно хотите вывести **результат** - добавьте скобочки и объект класса, для которого вызывается *нестатическая* функция-член:

```
std::cout << obj.GetCan1()<<std::endl;
```

а так

```
std::cout << TElection::GetCan1<<std::endl;
```

вы выводите адрес функции-члена `TElection::GetCan1`, а для этого и в самом деле требуется оператор взятия адреса `&`.

Comment: Большое спасибо